# Set background for ListView items?

Tags: java, android, listview, exception

So, I have this `ListView`, which I would like that each one of its `items` had a background (the same background for all of them). So far I've been trying to use this code:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> lv = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.countries_array, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
listView.setAdapter(lv);
```

---

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); ++i) {
    View listItem = listView.getChildAt(i);
    listItem.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext_custom);
}
```

It's simple, I increment `i` and then use it to know the position in which it is and it will set that items background, and it repeats until all items have the same background. Sound easy. Is there a better way to do this? If not, can someone please help figure it out why this simple code doesn't work? I'm pretty sure I'm missing something basic.

**Exception:**

```
05-18 15:08:45.659  10157-10157/com.example.fabiocompany.goquiz W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41917da0)
05-18 15:08:45.679  10157-10157/com.example.fabiocompany.goquiz E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.fabiocompany.goquiz, PID: 10157
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fabiocompany.goquiz/com.example.fabiocompany.goquiz.TopicosActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2328)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.fabiocompany.goquiz.TopicosActivity.onCreate(TopicosActivity.java:47)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**XML:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/bggoquiz"
    tools:context="com.example.fabiocompany.goquiz.TopicosActivity"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="20.0sp"
        />

    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_custom"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you need something else, please do tell, I'll try to help.

Comment: Which line is the NPE occuring on?

Comment: @StephenC `listItem.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext_custom);`

Comment: Would you mind to wrap this code and other nessecary source code into a full working example?

Comment: That means that `listItem` is `null`.  Now figure out why ...

Comment: @StephenC ya, I could get to that... I just don't know why.. I'm assigning it the item in the `i` position..

Comment: 1. Post exception stacktrace. 2. Post xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing all this you could create a new xml file named `listitem.xml` with textview as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tv_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background = "<give your desired background>"
/>
```

Modify your ArrayAdapter to

```
ArrayAdapter<String> lv = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.listitem, R.id.tv_item, <your array>);
```

As you are applying same background to all items simply setting it ones in xml will do the work. You do not require to loop through list.

Comment: Yup, this does solve it! Was looking for something like this since the beggining, but couldn't find it out, and I thought my incrementing code was a simple solution. I guess not.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your this method,.`listView.getChildAt(i);` this works only on the items which are currently visible
So this is how you need to use them.

```
final int numVisibleChildren = listView.getChildCount();
final int firstVisiblePosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
for (int i = firstVisiblePosition; i < firstVisiblePosition + numVisibleChildren; i++) {
     View view = listView.getChildAt(i - firstVisiblePosition);
     listItem.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext_custom);
}
```

Comment: `final Integer numVisibleChildren = listView.getChildCount();`, this returns 0

Comment: 9. Anyways, I'd rather user `.getCount()` because it will return all the items on the list.

Comment: but your getChildAt will only work on the visible items .. if you use getCount it will never work ..

Comment: where are you calling that for loop

Comment: @FábioSantos `ListView` re-uses the views created by the adapter. You should change the background in the adapter's `getView` method rather than through the `ListView`.

Comment: @Preeti Rao: hmmm.. I'm calling it at `onCreate`, but will probably move it to `onStart`

Comment: @simas is correct it is not a good practice of changing background out side

Comment: @FábioSantos that doesnt matter

Comment: @FábioSantos try putting it in onResume

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `listView.getChildAt` is returning `null` because the corresponding position has an invisible (or non-existent) object, then simply test for `null` ...

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); ++i) {
    View listItem = listView.getChildAt(i);
    if (listItem != null) {
        listItem.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext_custom);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, it's throwing me `null`